# Stock Symbol Typeahead error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp, yahoo-finance

I am trying to make this typeahead function work when a user starts typing characters into the input box.

```
<input id="visualtxtSymbolLookup" type="text" placeholder="type to search stocks" />
```

The script looks like this;

```
<script>
 $( "#visualtxtSymbolLookup" ).autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonp: "callback",
        jsonpCallback: "YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback",
        data: {
            query: request.term
        },
        cache: true,
        url: "http://d.yimg.com/autoc.finance.yahoo.com/autoc"
    }); // .ajax
    var YAHOO = window.YAHOO = {Finance: {SymbolSuggest: {}}};
    YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback = function (data) {
      var mapped = $.map(data.ResultSet.Result, function (e, i) {
            return {
                label: e.symbol + ' (' + e.name + ')',
                value: e.symbol
            };
        });
        response(mapped);
    }; // YAHOO.Finance     
  },
    minLength: 2 //source: function
  });
```

The only error i'm getting is:

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function  (anonymous function)